# LINQ Groupby a Date in a List of Object

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a List of the following object :

```
public  class Item
{
    public DateTime DliveryDate { get; set; }
    public String Order { get; set; }
}
```

How can i group this `List<Item>` by Date using LINQ?

I used the following query but didn't got excepted result in a group by dates Got a List object with a junk date of 0001/1/1

```
var r = from i in Items
        group i by i.DliveryDate into s
        select s;
```

Comment: What is the `Date` type here? In particular, does it override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` (or implement `IEquatable<Date>`)? Also, please give us *details* of what you saw when you tried, rather than just "didnt got any good results". Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for hints about asking a good question.

Comment: You've updated it to give *some* more information, but not *enough* information, nor any indication that your dates were valid to start with... (Oh, and what's `DliveryDate`? You've only shown `ChangeDateTime`.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry I cutdown some attributes due to large number of attributes in the class . i think now its be ok

Comment: @Sudentha, are you sure your DliveryDate is well initialized ? "0001/1/1" seems for like the default value for a datetime.

Comment: @remibourgarel i checked my method `ChangeDateTime = {12/14/2011 6:11:02 PM}` generates time properly !

Comment: @Sudantha: Please show a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem. Note that you're still talking about `ChangeDateTime` in comments, despite that not being in the question any more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should return what you need:

```
var listdategroup = from x in psrAlertLogItems.AsEnumerable<Item>()
                    group x by x.DliveryDate.Date into s
                    select s;
```

Comment: `Key = {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}` im getting a value as this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your ChangeDateTime  contains hour/time information , you should do

```
var listdategroup = from i in psrAlertLogItems
group i by i.DliveryDate.Date into s select s;
```

to get only the day component of your datetime

Comment: Dateinto is not found in by `DateTime` class

Comment: @Sudantha, remi was missing a space. Try it now.

Comment: Same results as @Kev IM sure that my data is correct but getting the query result with `Key = {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}

Comment: @Sudentha a group by clause do not create / alter data, there must be something wrong with your object. How do you check your results ? How do you initialize your list ?

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help u..

```
var sorted_lists = from sort in lists
               group sort by sort.DateInfo into sorted
               select sorted;
```

I'm getting the correct result..

Answer (score 0):

have you tried it using the extension method

```
 var itemsGruopedByDate = Items.GroupBy(item => item.DliveryDate ).ToList();
```

Just an alternative.

I hope its of any use.

Cheers.